# How can I see the nginx configration used by my heroku app?

Tags: nginx, heroku

I am trying to configure my app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but I am facing some problem with nginx not serving the public assets.

I want to take a look into my heroku app's nginx config to see what they are doing. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the heroku's nginx config using the nginx-buildpack

Read: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/maximzxc/nginx-buildpack#buildpack-instructions

And refer to this file https://github.com/maximzxc/nginx-buildpack/blob/master/config/nginx.conf.erb

Also read **Customizable NGINX Config**:

> You can provide your own NGINX config by creating a file named nginx.conf.erb in the config directory of your app. Start by copying the buildpack's default config file.

You may see the entire heroku config using the command `heroku config`

Comment: Does "Also read Customizable NGINX Config:" imply that one can set the config without using the nginx buildpack?

Does "heroku config" imply we can set nginx parameters using environment variables?

(In particular, I'm looking to adjust the `limit-request-line` parameter).